# ssis foreach loop error : Enumerator cannot enumerate

Tags: ssis

I've developped an ssis package with a foreach loop within another : the idea is to loop through the files (.xlsm) of a folder, then loop through the sheets of each file.

I used 3 package scoped string variables to get the files path, the sheets name and to configure the connection, and i used a data flow task within the inner foreach loop to load the values of my variables in a table.

Now when i execute the package, it starts looping, the values in the destination table are correct ( some of them are repeated more than once i dont know why ) but at the end the foreach loops fail even if the DFT is green.

the only error that i get is : The GetEnumerator method of the ForEach Enumerator has failed with error 0x80004005 "Erreur non spécifiée". This occurs when the ForEach Enumerator cannot enumerate.

and a warning : SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (2) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.

would you please help me figure out what went wrong ?

Thanks.

Comment: It would help if you posted some code.

Comment: Please copy the contents of your Output window and paste all the lines that begin with ERROR (or Erreur)

Comment: HI, this is is : " Error: The GetEnumerator method of the ForEach Enumerator has failed with error 0x80004005 "Erreur non spécifiée". This occurs when the ForEach Enumerator cannot enumerate."  this is the only error that i get.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to your problem is below:

Open solution explorer. Project->Properties->Debugging->Run64BitRunTime = TRUE(Change it to FALSE)->Click OK.